# Sacar cantidad de datos que sobrepasan un promedio en un vector en python

Tags: python, array, numpy

Tengo un ejercicio en el cual tengo que comparar los datos que almaceno en tres vectores (pero que finalmente junto en uno) que comparo con un promedio para sacar la cantidad de veces que los numeros ingresados en el vector sobrepasan un promedio previamente establecido. El promedio es un float y el codigo lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
#Funcion para determinar mayor que el promedio
def numero_mayor(num):
    for i in len(num):
        num > promedioM
        return True

#Funcion numpy para sumar vectores
import numpy as np

#Uso funcion list para devolver en lista y filter para extraer lo que se requiere
sumas=[]
sumas=np.concatenate((arrayA,arrayB,arrayC))
print(sumas)
listaAlta=[list(filter(numero_mayor, sumas))]
print(len(listaAlta))
```

El inconveniente creo yo es con la funcion del inicio, ya que antes de usar el for use un if pero solo me traia un numero de la lista, entiendo que termina la funciona apenas halle un numero que cumpla la funcion, pero lo que necesito es que me saque varios numeros que sobrepasen el promedio para luego contarlos con la funcion len.

PDTA: Este codigo me da error: for i in len(num):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Saludos

---

Codigo con datos harcodeados:

```
def numero_mayor(num):
    for i in range(int(num)):
        num > 13.33
        return True
sumas=[16,10,14]
#sumas=np.concatenate((arrayMA,arrayMB,arrayMN))
print(sumas)
listaAlta=[list(filter(numero_mayor, sumas))]
print(len(listaAlta))
```

Comment: no puedes iterar en un numero, pero si en un rango, prueba con `for i in range(num):...`

Comment: Me salta el siguiente error  for i in range(num):
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: no puedes iterar en el rango de un flotante, tienes que convertirlo a entero con `int(num)`

Comment: Tienes razon ya lo arregle lo del int para iterar, sin embargo continua arrojandome un 1 y no un dos como deberia. El promedio es de 13.33 y tengo tres numeros [16. 10. 14.] es decir, del vector deberia devolverme que 2 de los numeros 16 y 14 estan por encima del promedio. Al convertirlo en entero me rompe la lista de flotantes y por eso devuelve uno? perdon por la ignorancia, soy nuevo en python. Gracias

Comment: Heee... nunca haces una comparacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad es que no entiendo porque no haces todo con numpy

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
import numpy as np

def numero_mayor(lista,prom):
    return lista[lista > prom]
```

creamos la función que devuelva los mayores al promedio

creamos la variable promedio y las listas las convertimos a vectores

```
promedio = 13.33

vector1=[16,10,14]
vector2=[18,10,15]
vector3=[1,2,19]

vector1= np.array(vector1)
vector2= np.array(vector2)
vector3= np.array(vector3)
```

Si bien la función la podrías usar en cada vector, vi que en un momento los concatenas, ¡guarda!  es concatenar no sumar

```
total=np.concatenate([vector1,vector2,vector3])
```

bueno, ahí están los 3, solo queda si querés, asignar los resultados de la función a una variable y mostrarla

```
listaAlta=numero_mayor(total,promedio)
print(listaAlta)
```

Resultado:

```
[16 14 18 15 19]
```

y para el largo

```
print(len(listaAlta))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono la solucion.

Comment: @andavid ok, por nada.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema era tan sencillo como poner un `if` pues si solo pones `num>13.33` no pasara nada, debe ser una sentencia `if`, así:

```py
def numero_mayor(num):
    for i in range(int(num)):
        if num > 13: #sentencia para comparar
            return True
sumas=[16,10,14]
#sumas=np.concatenate((arrayMA,arrayMB,arrayMN))
print(sumas)
listaAlta=[list(filter(numero_mayor, sumas))]
print(len(listaAlta))
```

**Resultado**

```
2
```

Comment: El resultado me sigue dando 1, entiendo que el for me itera y el if me retornaria el true, pero al convertir el int dek vector no queda como un solo numero y por eso me da 1 o estoy equivocado?

Comment: lo siento no te entendí bien, probé el código y funciona, solo reemplaza el `13` por tu variable (ya sea *int* o *float*)

Comment: verifica bien lo que te devuelve `np.concatenate()` tal vez te devuelve listas en vez de números